# Running Linux commands execute hidden command to regenerate Backdoor

Tags: linux, monitoring, hacking, binary

My CentOS server compromised, the backdoor uploaded in /var/www/html/, I have deleted the backdoor and browsed the backdoor - to be sure it's deleted - it's surly deleted, but when I run any command such as "ls", "ps"... in any dictionary, the backdoor file generated again.

I noticed the files /usr/bin/ls , /usr/bin/ps ... has been modified in the same day of the attack.

After long auditing by using ( auditctl and ausearch to be clear) for finding which process generating the backdoor after deleting it, this is the results.

```
time->Sat Jan 13 17:44:37 2024
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): proctitle=726D002D69002F7661722F7777772F68746D6C2F6D61676E69746F2E706870
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): item=1 name="/var/www/html/xx.php" inode=35084690 dev=fd:00 mode=0100777 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 objtype=DELETE cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): item=0 name="/var/www/html/" inode=34033743 dev=fd:00 mode=040775 ouid=995 ogid=995 rdev=00:00 objtype=PARENT cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1705189477.956:12083978): arch=c000003e syscall=263 success=yes exit=0 a0=ffffffffffffff9c a1=1e670c0 a2=0 a3=7ffcc4acfea0 items=2 ppid=8050 pid=9434 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=193704 comm="rm" exe="/usr/bin/rm" key=(null)
----
time->Sat Jan 13 17:45:07 2024
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): proctitle=6C73002D2D636F6C6F723D6175746F002F
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): item=1 name="/var/www/html/xx.php" inode=35084690 dev=fd:00 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 objtype=CREATE cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=PATH msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): item=0 name="/var/www/html/" inode=34033743 dev=fd:00 mode=040775 ouid=995 ogid=995 rdev=00:00 objtype=PARENT cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
type=CWD msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995):  cwd="/root"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1705189507.759:12083995): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=yes exit=3 a0=7f22b8e630f9 a1=242 a2=1b6 a3=24 items=2 ppid=8050 pid=9465 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts2 ses=193704 comm="ls" exe="/usr/bin/ls" key=(null)
```

I want to know how do correct monitor and find the execution command that used to generate the backdoor by running any Linux commands or if there is a way to modify and inject these files /usr/bin/ls, /usr/bin/ps...

Comment: It can be resolved by reinstalling the server and taking an offline backup to investigate the files. Since it's a PHP file, the issue will likely become clear after examining it.

Comment: Let me guess, you disabled SELinux because it was annoying? Well, it would most probably had prevented this. Maybe you should learn how to use it after reinstalling the server.